sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called
I am using FastAPI + SQLAlchemy. I have a table User
class User(Base):
   id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
   organization_users: Mapped[List["OrganizationUser"]] = relationship(
    back_populates="user",
    lazy="selectin",
    foreign_keys=[OrganizationUser.user_id],
)

and a table OrganizationUser:
class OrganizationUser(Base):
id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(
    back_populates="organization_users",
    lazy="selectin",
    foreign_keys=[user_id],
)

There are many other tables and relationships.
I have recently started to add cascade delete to various relationships. This means that I have started to explicitly add relationships to User (for example, there was a relationship between User and UserSocialAccount, but that was only obvious from the ForeignKey to User in UserSocialAccount. Now I have explicitly added the relationship to User like this:
social_accounts: Mapped[List["UserSocialAccount"]] = relationship(
    cascade="all, delete-orphan",
)

)
The problem is I am now getting a sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet error when running the tests for OrganizationUser edit. The weird thing is that the error is not consistent; sometimes I run all the scenarios and they run just fine, and sometimes 1-2 produce the error. The error happens when I access
organization_user.user.email

I already use a selectin load for OrganizationUser.user, so I can't understand why I am getting this error. Previously, when adding cascade delete to Organization, I was able to stop the error by adding selectin to Organization.groups (which references entity OrganizationGroup, which is connected to OrganizationUser via OrganizationGroupUser). Didn't make much sense, but if it works it works. Now I have added a whole bunch of relationships to User, I don't want to use selectin for all of them. And I can't understand why a relationship between User and UserSession, or LoginAttempts, or Signup, should be eagerly loaded in order for me to access organization_user.user.email. I tried changing to
cascade="delete, delete-orphan"

to no avail.

Annoyingly from my experience, the greenlet spawn issue is just the first one raised and can hide the true issue. For me, it was no free connections available to be made to the db but could be any number of issues related to talking to the db

Could you share a little more code for your test case ? I've encountered many GS errors because of a mismatch of AsyncSessions. You have to make sure that the ORM object instance you are manipulating is part of the same session with which you query its relationship. In doubt use session.add() before.
Also note that the session referenced in obj.__dict__['_sa_instance_state'] is the sync session (which your async session is using behind the hood). If you are using AsyncSession in two different functions, you should pass it around explicitly.

I may have found the solution. I replaced all the cascade="all, delete-orphan" with cascade="delete, delete-orphan" (except for 2 places where I made them cascade="save-update, delete, delete-orphan". Before I had only done the replacement on the cascades in the User entity. Now I replaced them in all entities. We think maybe the cascade all option implies the refresh-expire cascade option, which was not desirable as we were using the asyncio extension. I will wait a while to see if the problem resurfaces, and if it doesn't I will mark this as the solution
